# Making a List that has multiple lines from a file (Python)

Tags: python

So I have a text file that has the following format:

''' hello world

this is a test '''

I would like to create a list in which the new line character is preserved. I would want my list to look like this:

''' [hello world

this is a test ]'''

The primary goal of doing this is so that I can iterate over each of the words and apply a caesar cipher encryption algorithm to it. 
How would I accomplish this? Sorry, I am new to programming.

Comment: This is not a valid list, do you mean `["hello world\n", "\n", "this is a test"]` ?

Comment: Or `["hello world\n\nthis is a test"]`?

Comment: I'm sorry I seem that I was not clear in my question. Let me start with this. Is there any way to have multiple lines of text saved in a list?

Comment: Which one do you want? `["hello world\nthis is a test"]`? OR `["hello world", "this is a test"]`?

Comment: @oldwooki the first one! sorry for the lack of knowledge about this.

Answer (score 2):

If your text file name is `data.txt`:

```
# To get ["hello world\nthis is a test"]
with open('data.txt') as f:
    result = [f.read()]

# To get ["hello world", "this is a test"]
with open('data.txt') as f:
    result = f.read().splitlines()
```